# How to run bash with commander.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface, node-commander

How can I run simple bash commands like `rm -rf directory` or `echo whatever` with commander.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run within your script command like so:

```
var program = require('commander');

program
    .version('0.0.1')
    .command('rmdir <dir>')
```

see full examples at: https://github.com/tj/commander.js/#commands